# Python: get value from column selected in other column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have simple `DataFrame` like below:

```py
df
   A   B    C err col
0  1  10  100   x   A
1  2  20  200   y   C
2  3  30  300   z   D
3  4  40  400   q   B
```

I'd like to create `df['result']` which has:

1. value of a column specified in `col`
2. value from `err` if there is no match (like with D in row 2)

```py
   A   B    C err col result
0  1  10  100   x   A      1
1  2  20  200   y   C    200
2  3  30  300   z   D      z
3  4  40  400   q   B     40
```

Comment: What is the issue, exactly? Have you tried anything, done any research?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Using [`Series.where`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.where.html), [`Series.isin`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html) and [`DataFrame.lookup`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.lookup.html):

First we make a series called `temp` which checks if the column names are in `col` else fills in `err`.

Then we use `lookup` to lookup the labels of `col` and get the values per row:

```
temp = df['col'].where(df['col'].isin(df.columns), other='err')
df['result'] = df.lookup(df.index, temp)
```

```
   A   B    C err col result
0  1  10  100   x   A      1
1  2  20  200   y   C    200
2  3  30  300   z   D      z
3  4  40  400   q   B     40
```

Comment: Thank you! Worked just as expected.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a function that will be able to perform this action for you.

For example:

```
def get_col_value(row):
    if row["col"] in row.index:
        return row[row["col"]]
    else:
        return row["err"]
```

And then you can use DataFrame.apply() to apply this function to each row in your DataFrame.

```
df['result'] = df.apply(get_col_val, axis=1)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `df.apply(..., axis=1)` to process the DataFrame row by row.

On a specific row, you can use the syntax `row.get(column, default)` to get the value for a specific column if it exists, but default to the second argument if the column doesn't exist.

Putting it all together:

```
df['result'] = df.apply(
    lambda row: row.get(row['col'], row['err']),
    axis=1)
```